# External hard drive no longer detected on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, external-disk, mount

My MacBook Pro froze and I have the spinning wheel. At that time I had my 2TB external drive mounted of which I have never had problems during multiple uses. I had to hold down power and just restart so I could get back on.

Now, since then, my MacBook Pro no longer recognizes my external drive. Nothing comes up at all. I tried unplugging everything, restarting the laptop, trying different outlets, and trying every USB port. Nothing. My drive just keeps blinking white-colored light when plugged in. Now, I'm pretty sure nothing was updated in terms of software. It is a WD 2TB Drive.

Comment: Does the WD drive show up in Disk Utility? Have you tried connecting it to another Mac to see if works there?

Comment: No, it does not show up. I just don't understand how it could work perfectly and then my laptop freezes and I have to hard restart while there was files transferring to the WD drive. Thanks for asking and taking the time.

Comment: Hint: when asking about MacBook Pro, do not include the tag `mac-pro`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Disk Utility (***Applications***>***Utilities***>***Disk Utility.App***)
When it has loaded, this may take a while as it tries to load your external drive, select the drive, which will probably be greyed out, then click 'First Aid' click OK and wait for it to run through its checks. Hopefully this will cure the problem

If the results throw up:

```
File system check exit code is 8.
```

then you have problems and unless you get the disk restored by a technician all the information on the disk is lost. I have just spent 4 days restoring all the files from a backup disk after reformatting mine as I had to start again!

Comment: It will not even show up in Disk Utility which I tried before. I bought this drive over 5 years ago and it has always worked to perfection. A really great product. It's just really infuriating it stopped all of a sudden. I purchased an SATA to USB cable to see if that does anything. It should be here tomorrow. Thanks for your help though. If anything else comes to mind, please share with me. I spent hours scouring the internet for answers and tried certain things. So, I'm not just coming here without doing research. It's just  last resort. Thanks again though for your time and thoughts.

Comment: Just verifying: You have Disk Utility set to show all devices, and not just volumes, correct? Have you tried plugging the drive into a different computer (another Mac, or a Windows box) to see if it shows up there? If it doesn't work on another computer, is it the drive, or the interface itself? Many WD drives can be removed from the chassis and connected via direct SATA cable connection using a USB adapter.